# Qiskit NoiseModel.from_backend gives wrong gate error

Tags: qiskit, depolarizing-channel, gate-fidelity

According to the Qiskit documentation, a gate error is simulated by a thermal relaxation channel followed by a depolarisation channel, where the parameter of the depolarisation channel is adjusted so that the average gate infidelity corresponds to the gate error from the `backend.properties()`.

However, if the calculated average gate infidelity of the thermal relaxation error is greater than the gate error of the `backend.properties().gate_error(gate,qubits)`, the thermal relaxation error is returned directly to the `NoiseModel`. This sometimes leads to large deviations (up to 100%) of the simulated gate error rate and occurs in particular when the dephasing time $T_2$ is small ($\approx 20\mu s$), since $1-\overline{F}_{relax} \approx \frac{1}{6} t/T_1 + \frac{1}{3} t/T_2$ (where $t$ is the gate time and $t\ll T_{1,2}$).

```
backend = FakeMontreal()  
noise = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)

cx_error = noise._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(1,0)]
error_cal = 1 - average_gate_fidelity(cx_error)
error_rep = backend.properties().gate_error('cx',(1,0))

print(f'gate error from noise model: {error_cal:0.2%}')  # 1.17%
print(f'gate error from backend: {error_rep:0.2%}')      # 0.70%
```

Why are too large gate errors accepted instead of applying e.g. only a depolarization error?